# chained select within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-options

I'm having trouble figuring out scoping within ng-repeat. I want to create chained selects, and I want to keep each row in the ng-repeat to exist separately in separate scopes. Currently changing the first select in any of the rows will change the second selects in all of the rows.

(Real life example: I have a form where I have to add cars, first choose a 'Make', pull its 'Models' from an api, and show models in the second select. Users must be able to add any number of cars.)

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="row in rows">
    <select ng-options="option.value as option.title for option in options1" ng-model="row.select1" ng-change="updateSelect2(row.select1)"></select> 
    <select ng-options="option.value as option.title for option in options2" ng-model="row.select2"></select>
  </div>
  <a ng-click="addRow()">Add Row</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.rows = [{}];
  $scope.options1 = [
    {title: 'Option 1', value: '1'},
    {title: 'Option 2', value: '2'},
    {title: 'Option 3', value: '3'}
  ];

  $scope.options2 = [];

  $scope.updateSelect2 = function(val) {
    if (val === '1') {
      $scope.options2 = [
        {title: 'A', value: 'A'},
        {title: 'B', value: 'B'}
      ];
    } else if (val === '2') {
      $scope.options2 = [
        {title: 'AA', value: 'AA'},
        {title: 'BB', value: 'BB'}
      ];
    } else {
      $scope.options2 = [
        {title: 'AAA', value: 'AAA'},
        {title: 'BBB', value: 'BBB'}
      ];
    }
  };

  $scope.addRow = function() {
    $scope.rows.push({});
  };
}
```

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/orszaczky/c4tcpang/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have the `options2` part separated for each row.

A simple solution will be to just save it inside the row object, but you might want a more elaborate data structure.

Here is a simple [example using your code](http://jsfiddle.net/jxtnrwe9/).

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in rows">
  <select ng-options="option.value as option.title for option in options1" ng-model="row.select1" ng-change="updateSelect2(row.select1, $index)">  </select> 
  <select ng-options="option.value as option.title for option in row.options2" ng-model="row.select2"></select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.updateSelect2 = function(val, index) {
  if (val === '1') {
    $scope.rows[index].options2 = [
      {title: 'A', value: 'A'},
      {title: 'B', value: 'B'}
    ];
  } else if (val === '2') {
    $scope.rows[index].options2 = [
      {title: 'AA', value: 'AA'},
      {title: 'BB', value: 'BB'}
    ];
  } else {
    $scope.rows[index].options2 = [
      {title: 'AAA', value: 'AAA'},
      {title: 'BBB', value: 'BBB'}
    ];
  }
};
```

Comment: I've been thinking of a way to store the options in a variable within the ng-repeat's scope, but this does the job perfectly! Thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! This would be a very cool way indeed, if I had all the possible options already, but I have to query an api to get the options for the second select based on the first selection. (I just didn't want to over complicate the example) - Unless... Options2 is an array, and I push stuff in it based on $index using an ng-change function...

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is my final solution. I realized that I can access the ng-repeat scope from the controller, by passing the repeat item as a function parameter in ng-change:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="row in rows">
    <select ng-options="option.value as option.title for option in select1options" ng-model="row.select1" ng-change="updateSelect2(row.select1, row)"></select> 
    <select ng-options="option.value as option.title for option in row.options" ng-model="row.select2"></select>
  </div>
  <a ng-click="addRow()">Add Row</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.rows = [{options:[]}];

  $scope.select1Options = [
    {title: 'Option 1', value: '1'},
    {title: 'Option 2', value: '2'},
    {title: 'Option 3', value: '3'}
  ];

  $scope.updateSelect2 = function(val, scope) {
    if (val === '1') {
      scope.options = [ //<-- this scope is the ng-repeat item's scope, from the function parameter
        {title: 'A', value: 'A'},
        {title: 'B', value: 'B'}
      ];
    } else if (val === '2') {
      scope.options = [
        {title: 'AA', value: 'AA'},
        {title: 'BB', value: 'BB'}
      ];
    } else {
      scope.options = [
        {title: 'AAA', value: 'AAA'},
        {title: 'BBB', value: 'BBB'}
      ];
    }
  };

  $scope.addRow = function() {
    $scope.rows.push({options:[]});
  };
}
```

Note1: In the `$scope.rows` array I had to pre add an 'options' array to each of the objects.

Note2: in `$scope.updateSelect2` the `scope` parameter refers to the ng-repeat item's scope (in this case `row`), and it's not `$scope`!

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/orszaczky/c4tcpang/2/)